# Bootstrap dropdown-menu is not targetable on collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm pretty much losing my mind over this. I have a bootstrap navbar which i like to style colors and etc myself. so I changed the link colors of the dropdown menu navbar using this code

```
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
  color:white;
}
```

it works fine so if i have menu item such as

```
Menu Item
    sub menu item
```

sub menu item turns to color white.

now the problem starts here.
If i make the screen smaller to collapse the navigation bar. dropdown-menu link colors stay as the default so i figured bootstrap is using a media query for that and no matter what i tried it didn't work. same technique won't work.

```
@media (max-width:767px){
  .navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated. I can do this using jquery but i really want to use css for this.

Comment: Please share your code what you did......

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question was that you have to target your classes after their breakpoints, I understand bootstrap having different classes in their breakpoints but having a different color and background colors on li elements can be very annyoing. so use a @media query to target whatever class is desired at that breakpoint